# Returning data from void** array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Suppose we have the following:

```
struct container
{
   void** array;
   function_pointer_typedef fp_t;
   int length;
};

void* get_data(const void* item){
   return item; //unsure. also produced warning.
}

void delete_element(container* c, void* item)
{
   /* 1. delete the array element pointed at by "item"
      2. reposition remaining array elements
   */
}

void* find_item(container* c, void* item)
{
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < c->length; i++){
      if(c->fp_t(item, c->array[i]) == 0){
         return c->array[i];
      }
   }
}
```

Further suppose that `fp_t` returns 0 if the two things compared are equal to each other (other return values for the function pointer are unimportant now). I'm also assuming, to make things easier, that the item in the second argument of `find_item` will always be in the array.

I guess I'm having trouble understanding how `void**` works. In the `get_data` function, we're supplied as an argument a `void*` pointer to an array cell, which is a `void*` pointer to some data object. So how do we get that data object? I understand the user has to cast it for it to be useful, but I still don't know what I'm supposed to be returning. I also know you can't dereference a `void*`, so doing something like `return *item;` (which in my mind seems like what we're trying to do- just get the `void*` pointer at the array cell), compiles with warnings/errors.

I guess `delete_element` carries the same type of confusion for me. We're supplied a `void*` pointer `item`, which points to a `void*` pointer array cell that points to the actual data. So we need to dereference the item somehow so that we can delete the array cell.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why does `get_data` take a `void*` and not an *index* ? Isn't the `void*` the data in the first place?

Comment: @WhozCraig the void* item is a pointer to an array cell (which holds a void* to the data). So I guess the item needs to be dereferenced somehow, so that the function returns the void* in the array cell instead of the void* that points to the array cell.

Comment: If it is as you describe, then `get_item` simply uses a pointer-to-pointer dereference. Using an intermediate pointer for clarity: `void ** tmp = item; return *tmp;` When dereferencing a "thing" referenced by a `void*` you must first "re-type" the `void*` back to a pointer-to-"thing". In this case the "thing" itself is a `void*`. That assumes I understand how you're doing this now, which is a *big* if.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to get confused by `void *` and `void **`. A `void *` is a generic container for any pointer-to-object. Any object pointer can be converted to `void *` and back again to the original value. (Note that a `void *` is not guaranteed to be able to hold a *function* pointer). It doesn't really matter *what type* of objects these functions are handling. They are storing and retrieving *objects* (that just happen to have the type `void *`).

> ```
> struct container
> {
>    void** array;
>    function_pointer_typedef fp_t;
>    int length;
> };
> ```

Your `array` member is simply a pointer to an array of objects.

---

> ```
> void* get_data(const void* item){
>    return item; //unsure. also produced warning.
> }
> ```

I have no idea what this function is supposed to return, but the reason you're getting a warning from this is that you are *removing* a `const` qualifier. You are turning a (pointer to) read-only object into a writable object. This is not allowed in C. To get away with this, you have to cast away the `const` qualifier. (`return (void *)item;`).

If `item` *really is* a pointer to an array cell (converted to `void *`), then you have to cast it to the original type before you dereference it to retrieve the object. (`return *(void **)item;`). But I *really* have no idea what this function is supposed to do. Ask your teacher.

---

> ```
> void delete_element(container* c, void* item)
> {
>    /* 1. delete the array element pointed at by "item"
>       2. reposition remaining array elements
>    */
> }
> ```

You're supposed to go through the `array` of objects until you find one that compares equal to `item`, remove it from the array by moving the following objects to fill that slot, and then adjust the `length`. The only thing you have to dereference is the `array` pointer, not the stored objects.

---

> ```
> void* find_item(container* c, void* item)
> {
>    int i;
>    for(i = 0; i < c->length; i++){
>       if(c->fp_t(item, c->array[i]) == 0){
>          return c->array[i];
>       }
>    }
> }
> ```

This function should probably return `NULL` if `item` is not found. Just `return NULL;` right before the functions closing brace.

Comment: Do you really have to search the array in delete_element? Because the second argument to the function gives you a pointer to the array cell to be deleted. So can you advance a void** pointer? I tried something like `*(((void**)item)+1)`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: The second argument is **not** a pointer to array cell. It's a `void *` which is the the type of object that is stored **in** the array cells. A pointer to array cell would be a **pointer to** `void *`, i.e. `void **`.

Answer (score 1):

`int*` is a pointer to int.  Given `int* x` pointing to valid memory for each of the following, `*x` and `x[0]` references the memory x points to; `x+1` points to the location `sizeof(int)` bytes after x, `*(x+1)` or `x[1]` references that location; `x+2` points to the location `sizeof(int)*2` bytes after x, and so on.

`void` is not type of object; so `void*` is a pointer to memory but not a pointer to something.  Given `void* y`, `*y`, `y[0]`, `y+1`, `*(y+1)`, etc simply don't make sense.

`void*` *is* a type of an object--it is a pointer to memory.  Given `void** z` pointing to valid memory for each of the following, `*z` and `z[0]` references the memory z points to; `z+1` points to the location `sizeof(void*)` bytes after z, and so on.

If it helps, pretend "void*" is spelled "pointer" (as if you are using `typedef void* pointer`), and is on par with "int".  So, if I have int q and pointer p, I can't do `*q` because q isn't a pointer to something, nor can I do `*p` because p isn't a pointer to something (strictly this is true).  But you can assign int's to other int's, and assign pointer's to other pointers; and you can allocate memory for `int*` just as you can allocate it for `pointer*`, and dereference objects of type pointer* just as you can with int*.

That's enough to answer your question, but to do what you want to do generally depends on a few implementation details.  If you're going to store memory as arrays of `void*`'s (aka, `void**`'s or "pointer*'s"), you will need to either require your user pass you a create function, or just allocate each element's memory themselves (or just handle it themselves, if you want to allow them to point to non-heap objects; it really depends on what you want to do; if you let them have items pointing to non-heap objects, though, you probably don't want to delete it).  Your code could delete the items easily enough.  How to remove items from this set is another implementation detail--depends on what you want to do.